# Can I customize the boot loading animation?

Tags: boot, opensuse, suse

Not the GRUB menu, the boot itself when I am loading into an os.

I want to change the loading animation/gif/video/whatever that is displayed below the brand name. For example, when booting to Windows, acer logo displays, and there is a circle spinner below it. Is it possible to change it? Not strictly asking for Windows, just an example.

Using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with KDE, and a Windows 10.

Bonus love and points if someone can point me to change both brand logo and loading gif.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Plymouth